# Запуск python скриптов по достижении времени

Tags: python, python-3.5

Пишу бота и есть два скрипта. Один парсит сайт, а другой постит то что напарсил в паблик соц сети. Как реализовать на python ожидание времени, которое задал пользователь(например в текстовом файле), и запуск скриптов, после достижения заданного времени?

Comment: вариант планировщика рассматривается?

Comment: @ivan_susanin желательно без планировщиков ОС.

Comment: @Dmitry_Che если не хотите планировщик ОСи использовать, то Питону придётся эту функциональность реализовывать (библиотеку поставьте или руками с помощью stdlib, если потребности простые). К примеру, в asyncio есть `loop.call_at()`. Недостаток, что вам придётся либо опять таки средства системы использовать, чтобы следить что ваш скрипт живой и перезапускать если нужно, либо снова на  Питоне реализовывать (supervisord).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас скрипт постоянно активен, то можно попробовать парсить указанный файл на заданные настройки. Выполнять нужные действия, засыпать, снова выполнять нужные действия, потом опять засыпать и т.д.

Можно использовать модуль [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). Если не хочется его изучать, то подойдут те же `json` или `xml`. Засыпать можно с помощью `time.sleep()`.

У `xml.etree` есть отличный [встроенный парсер](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xmlparser-objects), если `json` формат непонятен.

Если же вы хотите запускать скрипт с некоей периодичностью и не хотите использовать планировщик, то, боюсь, что чистым питоном тут не обойтись, и нужно будет подключать `bash`.

Comment: Что может bash сделать, что python не умеет делать?

Comment: @jfs да, в принципе, ничего, наверное. Просто очень много кода будет, либо много библиотек придётся подключать, либо, вообще, реализовывать. И, скорее всего, код будет трудночитаем, а также будет иметь высокий порог для поддержки и изменений.

Comment: вы пытаетесь сказать, что Python менее читаем чем bash?  (можно легко найти случаи когда bash более читаем и наоборот когда python более читаем -- но в целом ваше утверждение как минимум это спорно). Вы возможно хотели сказать, что удобней средствами системы воспользоваться (systemd, crontab) как я выше в комментарии к вопросу упомянул.

Comment: @jfs да, я неправильно высказался